# ¿Qué significa la sintaxis de ( objecto ) en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Me gustaria saber que significa esta sintaxis y cual es su nombre, estoy usando [laravel-excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/importables.html) y como pueden ver el creador instancia un objecto dentro de los parentesis
¿Qué significa esto y como se llama?

```
$array = (new UsersImport)->toArray('users.xlsx');
```

Comment: si mas no me equivico `new UsersImport` crea un nuevo objeto y con `->` indicas que quieres acceder a un método /propiedad de ese objeto

Comment: gracias ¿sabes como se llama esta caracteristica?

Comment: ¿[Acceder a un miembro de un objeto recién creado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php)? (Sección _new_ > _Ejemplo #6_)

Comment: Gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Más que tener un nombre o ser una característica del lenguaje se trata de la [precedencia de operadores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.precedence.php).

Al crear un objeto, por ejemplo: `new UsersImport` se puede guardar una referencia a ese objeto dentro de una variable:

```
$objeto = new UserImport
```

Y luego acceder a un método de ese objeto usando el operador flecha `->`:

```
$objeto->toArray('users.xlsx');
```

Aquí entra en juego la precedencia de operadores. El operador flecha espera que lo que está a la izquierda sea una instancia de un objeto. Por lo tanto lo siguiente causaría un error:

```
new UserImport->toArray('users.xlsx');
```

Eso debido a que el identificador `UserImport` no hace referencia a un objeto, es el nombre de la clase que se está instanciando. Entonces para que funcione se agregan los paréntesis, ellos alteran el orden de evaluación y primero se creará el objeto dentro de los paréntesis y después se evaluará la función flecha, de esa forma a la izquierda habrá una referencia a un objeto al momento que la función flecha se llame.

```
$array = (new UsersImport)->toArray('users.xlsx');
```

Comment: Es muy buena explicación y resolvio el porque y como funciona.